# Missing packages after clean Debian install

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, lxc

I've just installed a clean version of Debian (Wheezy) using the netInstall image.

I feel like there's a lot of missing package (that are usually installed by default when I used to use the full image for the install). For example Python wasn't installed.

Furthermore, when I installed lxc, it installed an other version (0.8.0 rc1) instead of the current 1.06 version.

How do I make my system install any missing package and install up to date packages?

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A netinstall is really minimal, you simply add what you need instead of getting a common denominator which includes stuff you may not need, a good thing really.

The [lxc version](https://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/lxc) of 0.8 is also correct for Debian stable, Wheezy.

More recent versions of packages require a different [release](https://packages.debian.org/releases) such as testing (jessie provides lxc 1.0.6-3), or unstable (sid provides lxc 1.0.6-4).

Comment: Once installed, is there a way to "update" Wheezy to have these "common denominator" packages? Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to add the backports package repository. It contains newer versions of some packages for debian stable, or packages that aren't yet in stable at all(e.g. nodejs).

http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

However, no newer lxc for wheezy there either.

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions for running LXC 1.0.7 on Debian Wheezy:**

For `lxc-attach` to work properly - Kernel > 3.8:

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

(containers also run just fine with the current 3.2 Wheezy Kernel)

Add to `/etc/fstab`:

```
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults,blkio,net_cls,freezer,devices,cpuacct,cpu,cpuset,memory,clone_children 0 0
```

Edit kernel options in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet cgroup_enable=memory,namespace"
```

& run:

```
update-grub
```

Install packages for building `lxc` & prepare sources:

```
apt-get install checkinstall libcap2-dev
wget https://linuxcontainers.org/downloads/lxc/lxc-1.0.7.tar.gz
tar -zxvf lxc*
cd lxc*   
./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --with-distro=debian
make -j4
checkinstall --install=no
```

& you will have a Debian package in the source directory.

You will also need to change line 18 of `/etc/init.d/lxc` to:

```
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/lxc-start ]
```

& add to `/var/lib/lxc/name/rootfs/config`:

```
lxc.start.auto = 1
```

Reboot.

**Notes**

You may want to install the dev packages for `GnuTLS` / `AppArmor` / `SELinux` / `SecComp` before running `./configure` to add support for them. Also `checkinstall` will moan about some missing directories which you will need to create before it successfully builds a package. With the above configuration you will still be able to drop capabilities & can now run [Unprivileged Containers](https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/) in Debian Wheezy.

[Debian Wheezy with LXC 1.0.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS8k6.png)